# Java source code parsing

Tags: java, parsing

I need to track down a java variable in a java file - which variable it got assigned to, which method it was passed to.

How should I begin with?

Should I use line by line parsing or is there any other method?

Comment: Use an IDE like IntelliJ.  It'll know how to find usages.

Comment: As suggested you can use JavaParser but it is not enough (I am a JavaParser contributor). You should also be able to resolve symbols and see which reference are resolved to the declarations you are interested into. To do that you need to build a symbol resolver. I described how to write one in http://tomassetti.me/how-to-build-a-symbol-solver-for-java-in-clojure/ but I am sure you can find other resources online. Warning: it is not trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are asked to build a huge mansion; and you start by asking: "should my shovel to dig the cellar be better round; or more rectangular". Meaning: if you don't understand that **parsing** a java program requires more than "line by line" reading; then you are doomed to fail.

Anyway, depending on your underlying requirements, there are two possible answers:

1. As suggested by duffymo, you might want to learn using an IDE which allows you to easily identify "variable usage" within a project; and make modifications via "reflection"
2. Start using a fully fledged Java parser; like https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/wiki/UsingThisParser